Are there any games where movement tricks (e.g wavedashing) have unpredicability to them and don't have 100% clear steps for reproduction?
I'm making a game where the main movement mechanic is that you drag your mouse to make the character move. The character is a fish flopping on land. The game is a 3d-platformer. So you drag or flick your mouse, and the fish will flop to move.
I have made a mouse flick detection system that calculates how hard the player flicks their mouse, and I set the flopping force based on the amount that the player flicks.
But because the mouse flick detection system is not perfect (e.g sometimes it will jump high even if I did a flick that felt really small), it's very unclear to me how to consistently execute different movement tricks.
I think I could fix those issues and make the movement tricks more consistent and easier to reproduce, by deeply examining how the code works in different cases. But I'm curious if there are any popular games where the movement tricks HAVE been unpredictable and inconsistent to reproduce?
I'm inspired by games where advanced players can learn complex movement tricks. For example wavedashing in Project M, or all the ways to move in Gorilla Tag, or Rocket League.
